# How to create a dictionary using a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have the following:

```
  children: [
    {
      name: 'test',
      path: 'test',
      meta: {
        label: 'test',
        link: 'test'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test/basic')
    },

    {
      name: 'test',
      path: 'test',
      meta: {
        label: 'test',
        link: 'test'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test/Basic')
    },

    {
      name: 'test',
      path: 'test',
      meta: {
        label: 'test',
        link: 'test'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test/Basic')
    }
  ]
```

I want to follow this structure, but programmatically create each dictionary using each record returned from an API call.

example api call

```
function getData() {
    axios.get(Url + input.value)
    .then(function (response) {
        json_data = response.data;
    });
}
```

so in python this would probably look something like:

```
test_list=[]

for item in json_data:
    dict = {
           name: item.name
           path: item.path
           meta:  {
             label: item.label,
             link: item.link,
                  },
           component: lazyLoading('testitem/basic')
           },
     test_list.append(dict)
children: test_list
```

How can I accomplish this in javascript?  I'm having a real hard time learning javascript after doing python.

UPDATE:

This is the full code block that I am working with.

```
export default {
  name: 'test',
  meta: {
    icon: 'fa-android',
    expanded: false
  },

  children: [
    {
      name: 'test',
      path: 'test',
      meta: {
        label: 'test',
        link: 'test'
      },
      component: lazyLoading('test/Basic')
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close:

```
const children = [];
json_data.forEach(item => {
    const dict = {
       name: item.name,
       path: item.path,
       meta:  {
           label: item.label,
           link: item.link,
       },
       component: lazyLoading('testitem/basic'),
    }
    children.push(dict);
});
```

Comment: so are you pushing each dictionary to 'children' which is a list?

Comment: Yes, the list (array) is initialized before the loop and on each iteration I just put the newly formed dict (object) into it. Is not what you need?

Comment: in the OP, is children a list?  It looks like children is a key and the list is the value?  Maybe in JS this is the same thing as children = list?

Comment: It's not clear from your code what children belongs to. You can't just do `children: test_list`, the colon means that it's a key-value pair in an object. If it is so, then you can initialize it like this: `children: []` and then push items with `obj.children.push(item)`.

Comment: I made a new post because I realize that my question was incomplete and I did not provide enough information. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48855114/how-to-properly-create-dictionaries-for-each-record-in-an-api-call-in-js?noredirect=1#comment84713622_48855114